# HTML Form возможность перетаскивания по экрану

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма

```
<form method="POST" name="calc" action="" id="form" class="colortext">
    <table class="tblCalc" cellpadding="0 cellspacing=0">
        <tr>
        ......
</form>
```

как сделать так чтобы ее можно было перетаскивать по экрану?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/drag-and-drop
что-то такое надо сделать

Comment: да точно, почитал. + еще обрамил форму в div и повесил события на клик и движение мыши. window.event.clientX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через jQueryUI с использованием функции [.draggble();](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

```
$('#form').draggable();
```